# ¿Por qué va tan lento mi scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy intentando crear un panel desplegable que contiene un scrollviewer. El scrollviewer funciona muy lento la primera vez que haces scroll; una vez hecho esto ya funciona correctamente el scroll y puedo hacerlo sin que falle, pero necesito que se cargue rápidamente. ¿Saben si hay alguna forma de cargarlo o hacer que vaya mejor? También tiene que poder adaptarse al tamaño del contenedor automáticamente.

Aquí está el XAML donde el contenedor es el un border, que se adapta al alto de la ventana.

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                MaxWidth="500"
                CornerRadius="8"
                BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="0,4,4,4"
                MouseDown="hide_panel" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0">

            <Grid  Width="500">

                <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="panel" 
                            Loaded="create"
                            
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>


                </ScrollViewer>



                <Label x:Name="lbl_row"
                       Content="&lt;" 
                       FontSize="20" 
                       Background="White"
                       Margin="0,381,10,381" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30">
                    <Label.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="30" Width="30" />
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Label.Template>
                </Label>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

Aquí está cómo creo los paneles para deslizar:

```
        My_animations anim = new My_animations();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            
        }


        public DockPanel create(int id)
        {

            DockPanel dp = new DockPanel();
            dp.MouseDown += down;
            dp.MouseEnter += enter;
            dp.MouseLeave += leave;
            dp.Width = 400;

            Border b = new Border();
            b.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(8);
            b.Height = 150;
            b.Width = 300;
            b.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            b.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(4);


            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Autoescuela\Desktop\a.jpg"));
            ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
            ib.ImageSource = bi;
            b.Background = ib;
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Content = id;
            lbl.FontSize = 42;
            lbl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;


            lbl.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Wheat);
            dp.Children.Add(b);
            dp.Children.Add(lbl);
            return dp;

        }

        private void down(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DockPanel dp = sender as DockPanel;
            Label lbl = dp.Children[1] as Label;

            MessageBox.Show("Click: " + lbl.Content.ToString()) ;
        }


        private void create(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int itemes_couint = 20;

            for (int i = 1; i < itemes_couint; i++)
            {
                panel.Children.Add(create(i));

            }
            DockPanel dp = panel.Children[0] as DockPanel;
            panel.Height = itemes_couint * 150;
        }
```

Comment: Intenta usar un [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Si que funciona mejor pero todavía cuando no has scroleado funciona mal, pero se nota una mejoría